# Two items in a row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to implement an answer board for a game whereby in a column there are 6 rows, each with two items. The first is the answer number (an image of a number actually) then a text field where I will reveal answers and thirdly an amount (I'll probably use a badge or add-on to the text field actually).

Anyway, I just can't seem to get it right. When I try something like the below the text input goes below the image for the answer number. I'm after a tabulated feel, but not sure whether a table is the right way to go.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-8">
    <!-- answers -->
    <img id="answer-1" class="img-responsive answer-number" src="../img/1.png" height="100px" width="100px">
    <input type="text" placeholder="answer 1">
    <img id="answer-2" class="img-responsive answer-number" src="../img/2.png" height="100px" width="100px">
    <input type="text" placeholder="answer 2">
    <img id="answer-3" class="img-responsive answer-number" src="../img/3.png" height="100px" width="100px">
    <input type="text" placeholder="answer 3">
    <img id="answer-4" class="img-responsive answer-number" src="../img/4.png" height="100px" width="100px">
    <input type="text" placeholder="answer 4">
    <img id="answer-5" class="img-responsive answer-number" src="../img/5.png" height="100px" width="100px">
    <input type="text" placeholder="answer 5">
    <img id="answer-6" class="img-responsive answer-number" src="../img/6.png" height="100px" width="100px">
    <input type="text" placeholder="answer 6">
  </div>
</div><!--row-->
```

Edit: so i know in the code above i'm literally listing the image, then the answer, then another image etc. What I'm after is the image then to the right, the answer, then below that the next image... etc. Just not sure if I need to embed more rows, create a table, use 'pull-left' and 'pull-rights' etc.

Comment: can we get a playground such as bootply.com or jsbin.com or jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: sure http://jsfiddle.net/m0atz/vk72t/

Comment: using <tr> inside table for each row with two <td>'s will get you the look you are after i guess..

Comment: You are using bootstrap right?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ravimallya/vk72t/3/ - I have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a  tag and  tags you are able to create a tabular feel to what you provided in your jsfiddle, My suggestion is that to avoid having the resources having a clumped up feel to implement a CSS and set up some padding so everything is neat.

http://jsfiddle.net/vk72t/1/ <-- Updated with some of the tags.

```
            <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <img id="answer-1" class="img-responsive answer-number" src="../img/1.png" height="100px" width="100px">
                <input type="text" placeholder="answer 1">
                    </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Edit Updated my example.

lastly http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp, should be of some help.

edit: Add in some TR tags alongside you're TD tags for them to sit nicely under each other.

Comment: thanks li x, this is certainly giving me more of the look and feel i'm after. thanks

Comment: I can also suggest looking into CSS more after you have defined the basic layout to get that point precision you may be after :)!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code in case if you don't want to use table structure.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <!-- answers -->
        <div class="row">
            <img id="answer-1" class="img-responsive answer-number col-xs-2" src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
            <div class="col-xs-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="answer 1">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <img id="answer-2" class="img-responsive answer-number col-xs-2" src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
            <div class="col-xs-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="answer 2">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <img id="answer-3" class="img-responsive answer-number col-xs-2" src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
            <div class="col-xs-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="answer 3">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <img id="answer-4" class="img-responsive answer-number col-xs-2" src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
            <div class="col-xs-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="answer 4">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <img id="answer-5" class="img-responsive answer-number col-xs-2" src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
            <div class="col-xs-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="answer 5">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <img id="answer-6" class="img-responsive answer-number col-xs-2" src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
            <div class="col-xs-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="answer 6">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--row-->
```